# DotNetOpenAuth or DotNetOpenId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to let user login with their Google, Facebook, Live accounts.
Very confused with which one to choose - DotNetOpenAuth or DotNetOpenId?

I've used DotNetOpenId, but it seems DotNetOpenAuth is kind has more features? and I don't particularly like Janrain, because it doesn't have the exit options, not in it's free version anyway.

I didn't find any particularly helpful articles on stackoverflow too.

If someone here had experience in both can shed some light on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

They're the same library, actually.  When DotNetOpenId had a major version release from v2 to v3 it was also renamed.  So for the latest version get it from http://www.dotnetopenauth.net